# Добавить текст в определенной строке к текстовому файлу

Tags: python, строки

Использую python 2.7

Имеется:
Текстовый файл, переменные a и b, которые вводятся с клавиатуры.
По текстовому файлу происходит поиск строки, в которой находится переменная a, после ее нахождения цикл обрывается.

Цель:
Нужно сделать так, чтобы после нахождения строки, содержащей переменную a, в эту найденную строку после символов `= "` добавлялась вводимая нами переменная b и все это сохранялось в этом текстовом файле.

Вопрос:
Как должна выглядеть функция добавления текста в определенную строку файла после определенных символов `= "`?

Comment: Используйте функции split и join, например. Так то можно регулярными выражениями, но это для вас будет сложнее

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, как можно с помощью указанных функций вставить переменную после конкретного символа. Не могли бы Вы привести пример, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, пожалуй join не нужен, если `= "` встречается в строке только один раз. Примитивный код:

```
string = 'sdfsdff df sdfsdf343 fsdfse f3r32f = "879" sdfsdfsd23 3r3r23r 3'
insert_string = '---3423-3434---'
split_by = '= "'
split_string = string.split(split_by)
print(split_string[0] + split_by + insert_string + split_string[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Если файлы не большие, то задачу можно разбить на две более простые:

1. чтение из файла в строки и запись обратно
2. изменение строк

По Задаче (1):

- считать файл в строку/строки
- заменить, детали в задаче (2)
- записать строки во временный файл (для надежности)
- переименовать временный файл в оригинальный

смотрите, как работать с файлами -- `with open...` и т. п.

смотрите, как работать со строками -- `split`, `join`, `index`.

По Задаче (2) вам уже что-то накидали.